# Visual Studio Code Python path set incorrectly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code and would like to use the integrated terminal to run or debug my code.

I have a python file in a scripts subdirectory. Everything runs correctly if I move it up one level to the project root directory. However, in the scripts subdirectory I cannot import the Python modules I have created.

If I add this to the top of my file it will work correctly:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
print(sys.path)
```

If I don't do that insert statement I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` exception.

This is my debug configuration:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```

What do I do to make sure the Python path always includes the project root directory, regardless of where the script file is located?

Comment: Have you added `__init__.py` file ?

Comment: Adding an __init__.py file to the scripts directory? I didn't because I'm not trying to import my scripts directory. But just now I tried that anyway and it did nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by setting an environment variable in the launch configuration.

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"}
    }
```

The last line did the trick.